# Javascript array association

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question about the best way of asociation of two arrays in javascript.
In *items* array the first number indicats the item id serving also as parent id in *promos* array.

```
var items = [
    [1, 'ZAPA BAR', '50.081809, 14.43036],
    [2, 'SUN Restaurant', 50.079809, 14.44436],
    [3, 'Jazz Club', 50.068809, 14.432336]
]

var promos = [
    [1, 'HAPPY HOURS']
]
```

Even though I was looking for some javascript function I didn't find any which would give me the intented result - ZAPA BAR has HAPPY HOURS.

How to make javascript to compare just the first number in each line (the item id) not the other elements in the array like GPS coordinations.

The solution should be fast because there will be much more items than three.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a freelance site where we write code for you

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = [
    [1, 'ZAPA BAR', 50.081809, 14.43036],
    [2, 'SUN Restaurant', 50.079809, 14.44436],
    [3, 'Jazz Club', 50.068809, 14.432336]
];

var promos = [
    [1, 'HAPPY HOURS']
];

var itemsLength = items.length;
var promosLength = promos.length;
for(var i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < promosLength; j++){
        if (items[i][0] == promos[j][0]){
            console.log(items[i][1] + ' has ' + promos[j][1]);   
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W7HGX/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your data to objects items and then ask on the key value:

```
var items = {
  '1':{name:'ZAPA BAR',lt:50.081809,lg:14.43036},
  '2':{name:'SUN Restaurant',lt:50.081809,lg:14.44436}
};

var promos = {
     '1': {name:'HAPPY HOURS'}
};
```

and then you can compare easily:

```
for(var val in items){
  console.log(items[val].name); // return the name
  console.log(val); // return the id which you can and check in promos (promos[val].name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the ammount of data, a database may be a wise choice.

I'm not quite sure why you've given each an ID as a javascript array has it's own used to identify items in the array.

So currently you've got two IDs:

```
items[0] = [1, 'ZAPA BAR', 50.081809, 14.43036]
```

If the names of your Promos are unique then maybe try this:

```
// WARNING: I've not tested the code, may have slipped up somewhere

var items = [
    ['ZAPA BAR', 50.081809, 14.43036],
    ['SUN Restaurant', 50.079809, 14.44436],
    ['Jazz Club', 50.068809, 14.432336]
]

var promos = {
    'HAPPY HOURS': [0]
};

function itemsWithPromo(promo) {
    var outputItems = [];
    promos[promo].forEach(function(itemID) {
        outputItems.push(items[itemID]);
    });
    return outputItems;
}

var itemsWithHappyHours = itemsWithPromo('HAPPY HOURS')
// itemsWithHappyHours = [['ZAPA BAR', '50.081809, 14.43036]]
```

Or you may even want to make the items into Object too as in array form i'm just guessing what each value means :)